# How to add loading animation to ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin form which starts a relatively long-running action (5-20 secs). It doesn't make sense to do it in a background task because I need the user to wait for it before continuing to work with the system. I want to make the form display some sort of "loading" animation while the operation is being performed but I couldn't find how to do it with ActiveAdmin/formtastic. I suspect that there is a feature of ActiveAdmin I could use but I can't find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: `disable_with` on the button is not enough?

Comment: It didn't work for me. Here's how I tried it: `f.action :submit, :button_html => { :disable_with => 'Wait...' }` and `f.action :submit, :disable_with => 'Wait...'`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should use disable_with ([check the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html)) with simple_form:

```
f.submit,
  'Submit',
  class: 'button',
  data: { disable_with: Wait... }
```

Since ActiveAdmin uses [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) under the hood, AA solution is a bit different:

```
f.action :submit,
  button_html: {
    label: 'Custom label',
    class: "btn primary",
    disable_with: 'Wait...'
  }
```

Comment: Tried it like this: `    f.actions do
      f.action(:submit, class: 'button', data: { disable_with: 'Wait...' }) + f.cancel_link()
    end
` but it doesn't work - the button is still active while the task is running.

Comment: I'm afraid this still doesn't work for me. It looks right and should work but something seems to be wrong with the `disabled_with` instruction. I tested it with `disbaled: true` and that works - the button doesn't do anything. I added an alert, so I'll know when the button works. What finally worked for me was this `f.action :submit,
               button_html: {
                 onclick: "this.disabled=true;this.value='Wait...';this.form.submit();"
               }`

Comment: By the way, I also tried using `data: { disable_with: "Wait" }` but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on ActiveAdmin.

```
f.actions do
  f.action :submit,
    button_html: {
      label: 'Custom label',
      class: "btn primary",
      data: {disable_with:  'Creating...'}
  }
end
```

The problem with not adding disable_with is not just visual. If you're using turbolinks, not adding disable_with could lead to multiple records being created in the database with one click.